# D7: How can I list duplicate entities based on the entity title and bundle, without custom coding

Tags: entities

There is a module for removing duplicate nodes, but how to delete duplicate entities (in my case ECK entities) based on title and bundle that are the same?

I was thinking that the search api module might be of help, which I installed. But listing duplicates requires something extra.

I also have Rules installed, but not sure how to create such rule.

What would be a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I created an aggregated view with counted title field, and filters on the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at the [Entity Bulk Delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_bulk_delete) module. This module provides a Drush command that can bulk delete arbitrarily specified entity types.

The caveat here is the module does not delete based on your specified logic of duplicate titles. For that, you can modify its [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7.x) in the [`_entity_bulk_delete_query()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/entity_bulk_delete/tree/entity_bulk_delete.module?h=7.x-1.1#n67) function so it matches your criteria for deletion removal.

Comment: This will be a bit too complicated or me to create. I will reformulate my question to exclude custom coding.

Comment: Essentially, you're asking if some one has created a module that deletes/lists duplicate entities based on a criteria you've not exactly specified (i.e. how do you determine which is the original among duplicates? Oldest/Newest?); it might exist, there's the [Remove Duplicates](https://www.drupal.org/project/remove_duplicates) module but it's just for nodes.